# How is equal_range supposed to work?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree, equal-range

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptree;
    const std::string entry = "server.url";
    ptree.add( entry, "foo.com" );

    auto range = ptree.equal_range( entry );
    for( auto iter = range.first ; iter != range.second ; ++iter )
        std::cout << iter->first << '\n';
}
```

I don't understand why this code is not printing. As there could be many **server.url** entries, I was trying to access them using `equal_range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equal_range` doesn't work with paths. After the add, your ptree looks like this:

```
<root>
  "server"
    "url": "foo.com"
```

But the `equal_range` is looking for children named "server.url" directly within the root node.

Also, you probably want to print out `it->second.data()`, because the former would just print "server.url" for every found entry.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptree;
    const std::string entry = "server.url";
    ptree.add( entry, "foo.com" );

    auto range = ptree.get_child("server").equal_range( "url" );
    for( auto iter = range.first ; iter != range.second ; ++iter )
        std::cout << iter->second.data() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if there are many server subnodes, each with a url leaf you can apply equal_range to the first level and then extract a child named url at each position